# Symfony, "super" admin user with hardcoded password

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Symfony 3.3 application with users stored in db with a normal User Entity as per [manual](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html).

I need to be able to login as "admin" (which is always the user with id=2), but with a fixed "master" password which will be hardcoded (its hash, not in plain text).

So this is the idea:
if the username is ***tech*** and the password is ***xyz***, the user ***admin*** must be logged in, and a custom role must be set.

I've tried as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html#using-a-custom-query-to-load-the-user), and I did:

```
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    if($username == 'TECH') {
        /** @var $user User */
        $user = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.username = :username')
            ->setParameter('username', 'admin')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();

        $user->setUsername('⭐ TECH');
        $user->setPassword('$2y$13$u...');
        $user->setIsTech(true);
        return $user;
    }

    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('u.username = :username')
        ->setParameter('username', $username)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

And in the User entity:

```
public function getRoles() : array
{
    if($this->isAdmin()) {
        if($this->isTech) {
            return ['ROLE_TECH', 'ROLE_ADMIN', ...];
        }
        return ['ROLE_ADMIN', ...];
    } else {
        return ['ROLE_USER'];
    }
}
```

But it's not working, the user is logged in as admin, but the ROLE_TECH role is not granted, and the custom name is not set (I don't know if that is possible, if not it's not so important)

Comment: Are you using FOSuserBundle ? If yes, what about the cli command `bin/console  fos:user:promote admin ROLE_TECH` ? You shouldn't modify the getRoles method with this kind of logic. This is the goal of the security role_hierarchy part, please see https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#hierarchical-roles

Comment: I'n not using FOS, and anyway I don't want to promote the admin. The admin is our client (it's a saas service), he can change the password at any time, but we must be able to login with a master password for technical checks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log in with a master password you could do it by creating an in memory user like this at security.yml

```
in_memory:
    memory:
        users:
            tech: {password: encoded_password, roles:['ROLE_TECH','ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN','.....']}
```

or you could store it at database and assign to it the proper roles. If you don't want the user/role be available for any action you could mark it as well with some boolean attribute. You are making a method like getRoles() a little bit complex just for one user.

otherwise try to refresh the user...

Comment: I also want to hide that user in all the users list, there are a lot of dropdowns in the app with "select user...", it this way it will be like a regular user, right?

Comment: If you manage the user by the in_memory option it will not be able in any of your dropdowns. This would be another user provider. So you have a database user provider and a completely different memory user provider. Read this [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded).

If you insist in load the user from database you should change the query(should have only one or two no matters how much dropdowns you have) to prevent that user from show in dropdowns and searches